# Get Javascript object using value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an object like :

```
Employee = { 
  0 : {"ID": 100, "Name": "ABC", "Level": 2},
  1 : {"ID": 101, "Name": "EFG", "Level": 3},
  2 : {"ID": 103, "Name": "KLM", "Level": 3}
}
```

I need the whole `Employee[1] : {"ID": 101, "Name": "EFG", "Level": 3}` and I have the value `101`. How do I get this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: this is not a valid syntax

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: "I have the value 101". Do you? How are you getting it? You didn't show us any code. Also show us how you define this Employee object in your real code. Like Manos, I noted that this is not actually valid JS syntax.

Comment: is this an array??

Comment: @Puneeth `SyntaxError: expected property name, got '{'SyntaxError: expected property name, got '{'`

Comment: @Puneeth your code still doesnot compile

Comment: Also this does appear to have anything to do with JSON. JSON is a textual representation of an object. You appear to be dealing with an actual code object. I removed the tag. Please ensure you understand the difference between JSON data and JavaScript code.

Comment: @Puneeth  have you tried to create an object with the code of your question?

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax may be incorrect but if it was more like:

```
Employee = {
  0 : {"ID": 100, "Name": "ABC", "Level": 2},
  1 : {"ID": 101, "Name": "EFG", "Level": 3},
  2 : {"ID": 103, "Name": "KLM", "Level": 3}
}
```

Then, Employee[1] would give you `{"ID": 101, "Name": "EFG", "Level": 3}`

View https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp for more information.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question: *"I **need** the whole `Employee[1]` and I **have** the value `101`. How do I get this ?"*

Comment: @FelixKling I read that as "I wanted to get the whole object, but instead my (unseen) code resulted in the value "101" instead. But yeah maybe they're saying 101 is the input, rather than the (incorrect) output. The wording is a little ambiguous. But my point is that following my interpretation of the question, this answer is entirely reasonable - although of course it still inevitably has to make an assumption about the real data structure.

Comment: Thanks for correcting, I was wrong. Edited my question. So I need `{"ID": 101, "Name": "EFG", "Level": 3}` and I 101 is returned from different function